# Two charged spheres connected by a wire and one is inside the other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential-energy, conductors

Two charged spheres are connected by a wire, a small sphere is located inside a bigger one. Both spheres are charged and connected through a wire. The charge of the small sphere is 20µc and the charge of the big sphere is 50µc. My guess is it would have something to do with the electric field but I can't seem to figure out what the impact of the electric field will have on the charge.

My question is: How would the charge be distributed between the two spheres?

[image]

Comment: The general answer to these problems is that all of the charges will be on the outside surface of the conductor (here only one conductor is present since the two shells are connected), which in this case the shell with a larger radius. Thus all of the $70\mu C$ would be distributed on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I demonstrate this with the use of formulas ?

Comment: are the spheres conducting?

Comment: yes,they are conducting

Comment: @Elcee_48 refer to any introductory em book like Feynman or Purcell.

Answer (score 1):

All of the net charge will be on the outer surface of the outer conductor.

Since the two spherical conductors are connected by a wire they are at the same voltage. Therefore there is no E field between them. So there is no net charge on the inner conductor and all of the net charge is on the outer conductor.

The charge is on the outer surface of the outer conductor by the usual argument for Faraday cages.